# What does "Graecōs Argōs" in this sentence mean? (LLpsI)

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

[image]

> Trōiānī vērō, cum ***Graecōs Argōs*** in patriam suam āvectōs esse arbitrārentur, tum dēmum post tot annōs portās aperuērunt atque exīre ausī sunt.

as is annotated, **Argī** is a city, but I can hardly understand the **cum**-clause:

> The Trojans in fact, not only thought ***Greek Argi***(?) had been driven away to their homeland, but also finally opened the gates and dared to go out after many years.

Comment: BTW the *cum ... tum* here is misleading: it looks like a "not only but also" construction, but actually the two aren't correlated -- the *cum* introduces a subordinate clause, while the *tum* goes with *demum* ("then at last").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Now, the Trojans, since they thought the Greeks had sailed away to Argos in their homeland, then, at last, after so many years, dared to open the gates and go out."

*Graecōs* is the subject of *esse.* It's an adjective used substantively, not an adjective modifying *Argōs.*

*Argōs* is the object of *āvectōs.* I gather that in the passive voice, *āvehī,* "to ride away", can take its destination as an accusative. It doesn't mean "to be driven away"; rather, the passive indicates the role of the subject in relation to the vehicle: the subject is borne away, carried away "by" the vehicle.

Comment: This probably is the intended meaning, but if so it feels wrong to add *in patriam suam* ("to Argos to their homeland"?), not to mention that not all the Greeks were sailing to Argos. The alternative is that *Argos* is supposed to mean *Argivos*, which doesn't seem too likely. Either way this seems like a badly composed sentence on Magister Ørberg's part.

Comment: @TKR Thanks—I was wondering about the use of the accusative case there. I tried looking in Book II of the Aeneid (above my level) for the passage that Ørberg was simplifying, and the original seems to include no mention of Argos: _…nos abiisse rati et vento petiisse Mycenas…_ I hope someone posts another answer, which might provide some missing piece to the puzzle.

Comment: @TKR Could _i​n_ +accusative here mean "…the Greeks had sailed away to Argos _on their way to_ their homeland"?

Comment: I don't think that's a possible reading of *in patriam suam* (and it still wouldn't make sense in terms of the story -- for a few of the Greeks Argos *is* their homeland, and the rest would have no reason to sail there).

Comment: @TKR Oh well! ......

Comment: @TKR There is a single passage in Plautus that Glare and Lewis and Short cite for *Argus, -a, -um* meaning "Argive." Glare ignores the problem with that particular hapax, yet L&S provide a much better reading, imo: "So the much-contested passage seems to be better explained than when, with Gronov. Observv. 4, 298, Argo is considered as abl. from Argos, begotten of a father from Argos, to which Argis in the plur. does not correspond."

Comment: @TKR I wonder if Orberg saw *Argos* as a variant of *Argivos* and went with that. Not ideal, considering the tenuousness of the reading, but it at least would exculpate him of a poorly composed sentence.

Comment: @cmw Ørberg has a marginal note on that line: "Argī -ōrum _m_: urbs Peloponnēsī." So, unless it means that the Trojans thought "the Greek city Argos had sailed away to its own country", I don't think Ørberg is getting an acquittal—unless there's some other basis for the accusative. I read the sentence as teaching the reader to avoid mischunking _Graecōs Argōs_ (and also to introduce _āvectōs_ before the line "Crēditis āvectōs hostēs?", quoted from Vergil on the next page).